# How can I multiply the elements of a list by all the other elements?

Tags: haskell

For example, `list = [1,2,3,4]`. `listProduct list` returns `[1,2,3,4,6,8,9,12,16]` i.e `[(1*1),(1*2),(1*3),(1*4),(2*3),(2*4),(3*3),(3*4),(4*4)]`

I remember seeing that there was something that did this, but I can't find that resource any more.

Comment: Why does your example not include `2*2` in the result? Perhaps you don't want duplicates. But then why does your example not include `3*3` in the result?

Comment: THat was a typo, thanks! It's updated now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why does your example not include `2*2` in the result?

If it's because it's the same as `1*4` --- that is, you don't want duplicates --- then

```
listProduct xs = nub [x * y | x <- xs, y <- xs]
```

On the other hand, if you do want duplicates --- if you want to multiply each number by each subsequent number in the list, and include duplicates in the result --- then

```
listProduct' xs = triangularAutoZipWith (*)

triangularAutoZipWith op = concatMap f . tails
  where f [] = []
        f xs @ (x : _) = map (op x) xs
```

You could use `triangularAutoZipWith` in a more efficient version of the first solution:

```
listProduct = nub . triangularAutoZipWith (*)
```

Comment: Thanks. I kind of wanted to avoid using nub. It seems like nub has some serious performance repercussions. Though this does work.

Answer (score 9):

You can write this in a simple manner using a list comprehension:

```
listProduct xs = [x * y | x <- xs, y <- xs]
```

However, it's more idiomatic to use the list monad:

```
import Control.Monad

listProduct = join $ liftM2 (*)
```

(equivalent to `listProduct xs = liftM2 (*) xs xs`)

To understand this version, you can think of `liftM2` as a kind of generalised [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) (`liftM2 (,)` is the Cartesian product itself). It's easier to see how this works if you specialise `liftM2`'s definition to the list monad:

```
liftM2 f mx my = do { x <- mx; y <- my; return (f x y) }
-- expand the do notation
liftM2 f mx my = mx >>= (\x -> my >>= (\y -> return (f x y)))
-- substitute the list monad's definition of (>>=)
liftM2 f mx my = concatMap (\x -> concatMap (\y -> [f x y]) my) mx
-- simplify
liftM2 f mx my = concatMap (\x -> map (\y -> f x y) my) mx
-- simplify again
liftM2 f mx my = concatMap (\x -> map (f x) my) mx
```

So the monadic definition of `listProduct` expands to:

```
listProduct xs = concatMap (\x -> map (x *) xs) xs
```

(Note that you don't technically need the full list monad here; all that's required is the [`Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html) instance for lists, and `listProduct = join $ liftA2 (*)` would work just as well. However, it's easier to show how it works with the monadic definition, since the `Applicative` instance for lists is defined in terms of the `Monad` instance.)

Answer (score 5):

Using...

```
import Control.Applicative
```

... with duplicates ...

```
listProduct list = (*) <$> list <*> list
```

... and without...

```
listProduct list = concat (mul <$> list <*> list) where
    mul a b | a <= b = [a*b]
            | otherwise = []
```

If you are in rube-goldberg-mood, you could use...

```
listProduct list = concat $ zipWith (map.(*)) list (map ((`filter` list).(<=)) list)
```

... or simply ...

```
import Data.List

listProduct list = concat $ zipWith (map.(*)) list $ tails list
```

**[Edit]**

Another way would be using `sequence`. With duplicates:

```
listProduct = map product . sequence . replicate 2
```

Without:

```
listProduct = map product . filter(\[a,b] -> a <= b) . sequence . replicate 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you've already got a few answers, but I'm going to toss in mine because I think the earlier ones, while all accurate, may be insufficiently helpful.

The easiest solution you've gotten for a beginner to understand is the list comprehension:

```
example1 = [ x*y | x <- list, y <- list ]
```

This syntax exists in some popular languages like Python, and should be easy to understand in any case: "the list whose elements are the results of `x*y` where `x` is an element of `list` and `y` is an element of `list`."  You can also add conditions into list comprehensions to filter out some combinations, e.g., if you don't want products where `x == y`:

```
example2 = [ x*y | x <- list, y <- list, x /= y ]
```

The more complex answers have to do with the fact that list comprehensions are equivalent to the **List Monad**; the implementation of the standard `Monad` typeclass for the list type.  This means that `example1` can also be implemented in these ways:

```
example1' = do x <- list
               y <- list
               return (x*y)
```

The `do`-notation is just syntax sugar for this:

```
example1'' = list >>= (\x -> list >>= (\y -> return (x*y)))
```

Landei's answer is based on the fact that if you're not using any conditions in your list comprehension, just Cartesian products, you can get away with using the `Applicative` type class, which is weaker than `Monad`.